# Office 2016 Addin - Is possible Open remote file on startup addin?

Tags: c#, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

Is possible open a remote file (url, xml, binary) ?

For example, I open a dummy docx with Add-In (from url) then the Addin retrieve a xml docx from url and put it in opened document (replace document dummy).

Is possible?

Thanks.

P.S.: I create a Addin and I retrieve a xml docx from url on open dummy file but I fail to put into opened document (replace).

Comment: The current Office APIs contain no command that allows you to directly insert a file into the current Office application's document. But it would be possible for your Add-in to read that document into memory and insert the content directly. I assume you want to put content from a docx into a docx? You can access the Office Open XML content using, for example, the Open XML SDK or the one for JavaScript, convert the content to the OPC flat-file, then write that OOXML into the open Word document.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are close to doing what you want. Once you have the docx file, then you need to base64 encode it. [Here's a SO post about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript). Once it is encoded, then you'll use the insertFileFromBase64 method on the [Body](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/word/word-add-ins-javascript-reference/body.md) object.

```
bodyObject.clear(); 
bodyObject.insertFileFromBase64(base64docxfile);
```

Here's a related example that does the base64 encoding on the service (different than what you want), and then [clears the dummy doc and opens the docx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Word-Add-in-SillyStories/blob/master/sample.js#L49) file in the client.