# Edit Word Online implementation choices

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, office365api, ms-wopi

I have a desktop app that essentially displays a list of ms word documents that are stored on a local server. A selected document
can be opened, edited by the user, and saved back to the store via a word add-in. 
I would now like to implement an Office Online version of the desktop application? 
What would be the best way to do this? If the documents were held in OneDrive and the users held Office 365 licences would the solution
be different/easier?

Answer (score 0):

this is totally doable, check out a very similar question (and answer :) ) here:
[Load document from local filesystem to Office online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890977/load-document-from-local-filesystem-to-office-online/39907860#39907860)

the destination/source of the documents, after you read this answer, its relatively irrelevant, but if you want to go Office 356 of course you can use the graph API to get and upload the documents you need. (pointers on the answer as well)